# How to link DCMTK with Qt on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, qt, dcmtk

I am new with all of these Qt, Dcmtk and CMake and I am suppose to use it for a school project. A lot of things are available on the internet but essentially for Windows..

I am trying to link Dcmtk with Qt and make it run on my mac but It is not working, the error is:

*Error output*

[image: Error output]

I have already built dcmtk with CMake (note the CMake wasn't generating the right paths...)

I know this error seems recurrent and I should add a LIB += ... 
But I tried a lot of different one and I couldn't find anything that solve my problem according to linking dcmtk

Here is my current code according to some found online:

*.pro file*

[image: .pro file]

*main.cpp*

[image: main.cpp]

I am feeling a bit powerless right now if someone could enlighten me.

Thank you!

Comment: Please copy the actual error message, don't link a picture. And do show at least one of the lines you tried.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know it was just linking the images, the error is "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"
I think I am missing some LIB include but I don't really get how it works

Comment: I tried : 1.  LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\DCMTK_1\lib"
LIBS +=-ldcmimgle -ldcmdata -loflog -lofstd ... which is obviously for windows ---

2.LIBS += -framework AppKit
LIBS += -framework CoreAudio
LIBS += -framework AudioToolbox ---

3.DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++"
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++"
---
4. LIBS += "/Système/Bibliothèque/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CoreFoundation.h"

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to link with dcmimage?

try adding LIBS += -ldcmimage

Comment: Also, the dcmtk forums mention that linking order is important, I use linking order: LIBS += -lofstd -ldcmdata -ldcmimgle -ldcmimage -loflog

Comment: I tried to link as you say but I still have the same error. I wonder if some path aren't overlapping in my computer and lead to this error